# Mobile Safari file upload popup position

Tags: html, ipad, mobile, input, safari

I have a problem in Mobile Safari on my iPad. I have a invisible file input. When I click this button, the popup where you can choose to take a new picture or choose a picture which already exists on your iPad, doesn't popup underneath the file input but randomly somewhere on the screen.

Does anyone know why this happens or if it is possible to change the position of this popup?

Answer (score 1):

This issue can be caused by artificially triggering a click on an input element (when a user clicks on another button).

If you're doing this, then this is likely the cause.

Comment: But what is the alternative to triggering click on the input element?

Answer (score 1):

Confirm the problem, jQueryMobile 1.4, iOS 7, iPad4.

```
$('#notePic').on('vclick', function() {
  $('#takePictureField').trigger('click');
});
```

Looks like popup appears over item that last triggered any event.

To solve the problem it's possible to put transparent input above button:

```
<a data-role="button"></a>
<input type="file" data-role="none" style="position: absolute !important; left: 0px; top: 0px; clip: rect(0px,40px,40px,0px); opacity: 0.0; padding: 10px 0px" name="notePic" />
```